# Greasemonkey: Click on black spot in captcha image

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey, userscripts

Is it possible to let a GM script click the black spot in this captcha?
Ofcourse the black spot is after every refresh on another place.

Hopefully someone could help me getting started.

[image: Captcha]

Comment: with some kind of imagereader.. why not?

Comment: Is it actually an `<img>` (or canvas, flash, etc)? Which browsers do you need to support? Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: raise the contrast by 250 levels, reduce to B+W, threshold 128, scale to 20X20, grab image data, find first coords under pixel value 0, multiply by 20 to get orig coods of black spot.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté It is included at the page as a input type="image" with the image as source. I would like to support FireFox.

Comment: @dandavis Could you help me with the functionnames?

Comment: considering the topic, i've said enough already. you might want to do a 3px blur before your contrast or threshold. then it's something like z=imagedata.indexOf(0), x=z%w, y=~~(z/w).